# Optimization question: maximize quadratic objective with semidefinite constraints

Tags: nonlinear-optimization, quadratic-programming

I recently encountered the following optimization problem:

$\max \|AX\|_F^2$

subject to: $X\succeq0$ and $Xb_i\leq c_i$ for a collection of $T$ conditions: $i=1,\ldots,T$.

Matrices $A$ and $X$ are square and symmetric, and $c$ is a column vector.

I know from Wikipedia that the general "quadratically constrained quadratic optimization" problem is NP-hard. However, can this special form be solved efficiently?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What does $BX \le c$ mean with matrices $B$, $X$ and a vector $c$?

Comment: Sorry, typo corrected.

Comment: The problem is simply not convex.